# Do not understand exception, cant convert to readable text

Tags: c#, exception

I have a hash table which stores IPs as strings for the key and an object of my creation in the corresponding value.

I keep getting an exception at `foreach (DictionaryEntry info in MasterHash.Keys)`.
More specifically it happens as the debugger gets to `DictionaryEntry`.
I have tried to provoke a message from my try catch statement but the compiler does not like me trying to cast `e` to `.ToString` or `.Message`.

```
private void UpdateMap(Hashtable masterHash)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (DictionaryEntry info in masterHash.Keys)
        {
            AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash axFlash = wfh.Child as AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash;
            IPInstance foo = (IPInstance)info.Value;

            axFlash.CallFunction(foo.GetMarkerCall().ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be an invalid cast exception. masterHash.Keys is not a DictionaryEntry. The keys should be strings (your IP string).

EDIT:

```
ICollection MyKeys = MyTable.Keys;

foreach (object Key in MyKeys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(Key.ToString());
}
```

Comment: I tried Implementing the foreach with string instead of Dictionary entry. The IDE is now complaining: Error 1 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How do I retrieve my objects while using string in the foreach?

Comment: Looking a little more closely, a hashtable's keys are enumerated as an ICollection. I'll edit a suggestion.

Comment: If you are using .net 3.0 or higher you can use `var` instead of object in your `foreach` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you are unable to get the values of the exception caught.  However, you said that you

> stores IPs as strings for the key

but instead you are looping through the keys but expect DictionaryEntry.

Try doing:

`foreach(String s in masterHash.Keys)`

or something like that instead.

Comment: I tried Implementing the foreach with string instead of Dictionary entry.  The IDE is now complaining: Error 1 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: How do I retrieve my objects while using string in the foreach?